# How to set button always in bottom layout android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a register layout, i want to set button always in bottom, but when i click one of textfield, buttons are not under the last element / textfield, but is above textfield. I intend to make it relative, if the keyboard does not appear, it will appear like in the picture, there is a space between the text field and a button, but when the keyboard appears, I intend to eliminate the space.

[image: image1]
[image: image2]

this is my layout xml :

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/login_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include layout="@layout/padding" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:hint="Email Address"/>

        <EditText
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:hint="Password"/>

        <EditText
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/editText3"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:hint="First Name"/>

        <EditText
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/editText4"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:hint="Last Name"/>

        <EditText
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="phone"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/editText5"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:hint="Phone"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/forgottext"
        android:layout_below="@+id/login_layout"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Forgot?"
        android:autoLink="web"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

    <com.gc.materialdesign.views.ButtonRectangle
        android:id="@+id/login_bt"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:text="Sign Up"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:background="@color/material_deep_teal_500"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Use Linear Layout instead RL. <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
   >     ///......////// </LinearLayout> and set  android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan" in your manifest

Comment: thank, but i need to scroll, but this is usefull, so i just add adjustResize|stateHidden. thanks :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make a LinearLayout with two Layouts (1. Layout with all your editViews, 2. Button). Give the main LinearLayout

```
android:layout_weight="1"
```

and inner Layout

```
android:layout_weight="1"
```

Both inners should be match_parent, then your button always will be on the bottom (even if the keyBoard is displayed)